# Looking for documentation on Kenwood NX-700 AFO and DEO Signals

Tags: vhf, kenwood, audio-interface

I'm studying the accessory connector (DB-25) from a Kenwood NX-700 radio. It seems that I might use the AFO and/or DEO signals, but I haven't been able to get proper documentation on such pins/signals. I'd like to get the audio data received and hopefully send data via other pins on this connector too, avoiding the use of the standard mic/PTT/speaker connectors. Also, is there any pin that provides a S-meter like output?

Could anyone please assist me on getting more info on these?

Answer (score 1):

- AFO is filtered, squelched audio.
- DEO is raw discriminator audio.

Here is a PDF of the [NX-700 pin documentation](https://forums.radioreference.com/attachments/kenwood-ef-johnson-forum/29815d1287024000-nx-700-800-25-pin-accessory-connector-nx700out.pdf).